# Can't access class variables through array of objects (unityscript/Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Here is my class

```
public class ItemClass extends System.ValueType
{
    public var itemTexture : Texture2D;
    public var descriptionTexture : Texture2D;

    public function ItemClass (item:Texture2D, desc:Texture2D)
    {
        itemTexture = item;
        descriptionTexture = desc;
        //GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(179, 140, 200, 202), attHighlight4);
    }
}
```

Here is my array

```
var Test = new ItemClass(Axe, AxeDescription);
public var itemArray = new ArrayList();
itemArray.Add(Test);
```

If I try to access itemArray[0].itemTexture Unity tells me that itemTexture is not a member of 'Object'.

Looking for the syntax to access itemTexture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this wiki page helpful: [Which Kind Of Array Or Collection Should I Use?](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use%3F#ArrayLists)

`ArrayLists` contain 'objects'. When you retrieve your item back out of an ArrayList, it's unclear to the runtime or compiler what type that item was originally. You need to provide a more explicit type hint about the item, such as below:

```
var myItem : ItemClass  = itemArray[0]
var myTexture           = myItem.ItemTexture
```

You might consider using `List<>` instead, for the reasons covered in the wiki page.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.  I'm a c++ programming just getting into Javascript.  A lot of things that are simple in c++ are proving to be a bit more work.